# async logger thread safe

Tags: c++, thread-safety

I have a simple logger written, I have a problem.

```
pthread_mutex_t l_mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
class logger
{
   public:
      logger() { }


      template<typename T>
      logger& operator<<(const T& t)
      {
         pthread_mutex_lock(&l_mutex);
         std::cout  << t << std::flush;
         pthread_mutex_unlock(&l_mutex);
         return *this;
      }

   protected:
};

static const unsigned char endline = '\n';
static logger log;
```

When I use the logger however from two threads, it does exactly what it shouldn't do. The calls to;

Thread #1

```
log << "Hello " << 1;
```

Thread #2

```
log << "Goodbye " << 2;
```

The output gets interleaved because of the way operator<< is implemented. How would I be able to get natural use of << AND have it be atomic in nature so instead of

> Hello 2 Goodbye 1

We are guaranteed to get

> Hello 1 
>   Goodbye 2

Thanks in advance. Is there a silver bullet there or is a new approach required?

Thanks

G

Comment: Writing the call in it's long form `log.operator<<("Hello ").operator<<(1);` you can see you have 2 separate calls to `operator<<`  Either build the complete message before calling `operator<<` or lock around both calls.

Comment: Your `operator<<` **is thread safe**. What is not thread safe is multiple calls to that operator. And it looks like that's what you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a helper object.

Change your existing `<<` overload method to return a helper object, something like:

```
  template<typename T>
  loggerHelper operator<<(const T& t)
  {
     return loggerHelper{} << t;
  }
```

Your `loggerHelper` class must have the following properties:

- its constructor should acquire the mutex. And the destructor will unlock the mutex. Run-of-the-mill RAII design pattern, but with one additional twist:
- the object must correctly, and precisely, implement move semantics. The moved-from object instance will not release the aforementioned mutex, the moved-to object will be responsible for that. The copy constructor and the assignment operator must be `delete`d.
- the object implements the "real" `<<` operator overload, using `std::cout` and returns `*this`. This will trigger move semantics, and passing the "hot potato" of releasing the mutex to the next `<<` operator invocation, or if there is none, finally destroying the end-of-the-road helper class instance.

If all these steps are done correctly, then I would expect the end result will be the mutex on the main `logger` object getting acquired once, and not released until all the daisy-chained `<<` operators are finished with their responsibilities.

The first `<<` operator gets kicked off by the original `<<` operator, above, and they all get processed, for real, by the helper object's `<<` operator overload, with move semantics taking care of preserving the underlying mutex lock, and releasing it at the end.

Comment: awesome! I'll go ahead and give that a try. Appreciate that. Cheers.